# How to define a route for Iron Router in a smart package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am using iron:router@1.0.0-pre3 with meteor 9.3.1.

I am creating a smart package. I want to define routes inside the smart package and not in the main app.js file.

I tried adding following code in the .js file for smart-package:

```
Router.route('/path', function () {
  this.render('someTemplate');
});
```

The above code gives a "Router not defined" error. Don't know what should be added to "api.use" in "Package.onUse(function(api)" for Iron:Router in the "package.js" file.

Is it possible to define routes inside smart-package? How can I do this?

**Update**:

After adding `iron:router` to `api.use` the "Router not defined" error is gone.

However, the route is still not working. I have added the route in `mypack.js`. **`mypack.js` is only available to client.**

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('METEOR@0.9.3.1');
  api.use(['iron:router', 'templating'], 'client');
  api.addFiles(['mypack.js', 'mypack.html'], 'client');
});
```

Comment: you should edit this to include the link to github where it explains why it's not working

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to define a dependency on the iron router package in your package. In `package.js`, in the call to `api.onUse`, just add `api.use('iron:router')`.

Comment: Thanks! "Router not defined" error is now gone. I have updated the question. Don't know how to declare routes inside js file that is only available to client.

Comment: @AnishSingh, you should be able to use it as usual, for example: `Router.route('/home', {name: 'home', template: 'home'})`.

Comment: sadly it's not working. In fact, if I place `Router.route('/', function() {
        this.render('hello');
    });` inside `if (Meteor.isClient)` in the main app.js file, the route stops working even without smart-package coming into picture.

Comment: Oups, I may have been miss leading you a bit. `api.use('iron:router')` will add the latest stable version of iron router (9.4 at the moment, I think). Which version do you use in your app? In 9.4, the route should look like this instead: `Router.map(function(){ this.route('home', {path: '/home', template: 'home'}) })`.

Comment: iron:router version is 1.0.0-pre3. Seems like adding a route from inside a smart-package is not possible. Refs: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/897